# C# Google Admin API - Enable Gmail and other apps

Tags: c#, gmail, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-api-dotnet-client

I've been working with the Google Admin API C# library for a few days now to create / delete users. Which I have got working.

However when I create a new user via the API, the Gmail app is turned off by default (along with other apps) and so when the user logs gmail for the first time they are presented with the message

> "We are sorry, but you do not have access to Gmail. Please contact your organisation administrator for access."

I then have to go and turn it on manually via admin.google.com

I haven't yet managed to find any docs or mentions anywhere on how to turn on/off the apps via the API. Is this actually possible?

here is my code for creating the user:

```
User user = new User
{
    Name = new UserName
    {
        FullName = employee.DisplayName,
        GivenName = employee.FirstName,
        FamilyName = employee.LastName
    },
    PrimaryEmail = employee.Email,
    Password = "P@ssw0rd!.",
    OrgUnitPath = "/UK/sales",
    ChangePasswordAtNextLogin = true,
    IncludeInGlobalAddressList = true
};

UsersResource.InsertRequest request = ds.Users.Insert(user);
await request.ExecuteAsync();
```

Note: `ds` is a `DirectoryService` with scopes `AdminDirectoryUser`, `AdminDirectoryGroup` and `AdminDirectoryOrgunit`

Comment: please edit your question and include your code

Comment: @DaImTo I don't have any code relating to this. I have working code to create users but I can't find any code to enable apps which is what my question is about

Comment: you are creating a new user via the api you have code some where or this isnt coding related

Comment: @DaImTo OK I've added the code I'm using to create the user.

Comment: can i see the authorization code?